# Add a class to the vue element

Tags: vue.js

I have a `div` like this:

```
   <div
      v-for="(server, index) in server_list"
      class="server_item border_999_top_left_right"  // there I want to add a more class under a certain conditions
    >
```

I have a more class `border_bottom`, I want add it if there meets a condition.

How to add the `class="border_bottom"` when it meets a condition such as `1==1`?

Comment: @VitalyMigunov Can I use both the `class="a"` and `:class={'b':conditions}`?

Comment: nope but you can create a method that will return your classes + conditional classes if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for doing this:

```
<div
  v-for="(server, index) in server_list"
  :class="get_class(index)"  // there I want to add a more class under a certain conditions
>
```

The condition method:

```
get_class(index) {

    return {
      'server_item': true,
      'border_999_top_left_right': true,
      'more_class': index === 10
    }
}
```